# How to check if child component has unsaved data before closing

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my app a previous developer used a Infragistics OverlayService to display some components in a modal mode which worked ok but over time while using other 3 party controls i found many issues like the zIndex etc and some other strange behavior. So what i am trying to do without breaking everything is to replace the OverlayService with the Angular Dialog. In process of doing so i come across the issue how to close the dialog if user clicks on the x in the right corner.
Normally that would not be an issue as i just could call the

```
this.dialogRef.close()
```

but that's not the case here since the X is in a different component. When user opens the dialog i use

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateQuickMailComponent,
     {
       disableClose: true, position: {
        top: '0px',
        right: '0px'
       },
        panelClass: 'inner-no-pad-dialog',
        autoFocus: false
      })
```

then the template code for this component looks like this

```
<app-header-container title="New Mail">
    <div class="sample-column card-wrapper">
        <app-quick-mail-form (edit)="edit($event)"></app-quick-mail-form>
    </div>
</app-header-container>
```

app-quick-mail-form is the form that has all the logic and from where i can close the dialog just fine with the this.dialogRef.close(). What i need is a way to do the same from the app-header-container which has the X in right corner on click.

My app-header-container template

```
<div class="container__element">
    <igx-navbar title="{{ title }}">
        <igx-icon (click)="dismiss()">close</igx-icon>
    </igx-navbar>

    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

So I can close the dialog by using the **this.dialogRef.close()** and referencing private **dialogRef: MatDialogRef** but how can I check before I call the close() if the underlaying form is dirty to ask user if he wants to safe before closing ?
Since this component is used by more then one component i cant hardcode the references.

So i am open for any ideas or suggestions

Comment: Maybe i'm overlooking something, but is there any reason this can't be simply handled in a service?
When I make a "global" component that is reused across my application let's call it bulk-mailer.component i usually create an accopanying bulk-mailer.service and bundle it all together in a bulk-mailer.module (that's how angular-material does it too). 
So make a dialog-handler.service, have a "active dialog" reference and perform the  checkBeforeClose in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `@Input` to your `<app-header-container>` component, to indicate whether or not dismissing should be allowed.

Each component that uses it could pass in whatever criteria makes sense:

```html
<app-header-container title="New Mail" [allowDismiss]="!mailForm.isDirty">
    <div class="sample-column card-wrapper">
        <app-quick-mail-form #mailForm (edit)="edit($event)"></app-quick-mail-form>
    </div>
</app-header-container>
```

```js
@Input() allowDismiss = true;

public dismiss() {
  if(!this.allowDismiss) {
    return;
  }

  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

Comment: That looks like a valid solution, the only question is how do i to get to push the form.dirty from the app-quick-mail-form to the app-header-container

Comment: If that component has a property `isDirty` on it, you could add a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) to the`app-quick-mail-form`, then access it when you assign `allowDismiss`, see update.

Comment: Thanks, it seems i can not just watch the dirty value of the mailForm via mailForm.form.dirty but will have to subscribe to form changes and update a variable with the form.dirty value.

Comment: You can probably set up an `@Output()` on your mail form to emit when the dirty state changes.  Something like:  `@Output() isDirty = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(map(() => this.form.dirty), distinctUntilChanged())`.  Then use that to set a local variable in the parent component like `<app-quick-mail-form (isDirty)="setIsDirty($event)" (edit)="edit($event)"></app-quick-mail-form>`

Comment: thanks, that might work but i went similar rout creating a var isDirty and subscribed to valuechange for form and if pristine changed i set isDirty which was passed to the header. so no need to do the Output part. It was just interesting that i can read in header the isDirty but no values of the form.